Supermarket online purchases pickup: Struggling with the problem formulation
I am working on problem formulation, the scenario is as follows: there are several online purchases in a supermarket that someone has to pick in order to prepare them and, a posteriori, delivery. Each order has several items from 1 to N, and of course each item is at a given location on the supermarket. To optimize the process, the person will group the purchases in groups up to 4 purchases. The problem is how to group the orders to minimize the walking distance. There is a table with coordinates of each location, so it is possible to estimate the Manhattan distance between each pair of locations.
I have started a problem definition, initially to get a group of 4 which are the most efficient to pick together:

O is the total number of orders to be picked
L is the total number of locations in the supermarket
D is the locations distance matrix, where Di,j is the distance between location i and j
T is the location travels matrix, where Ti,j indicate that location j will be visited after location i
Xi indicates that order i will be included in the group

Objective function:
$$
min \sum_{i=1}^{L} \sum_{j=1}^{L} T_{i,j} * D_{i,j}
$$
I have started to write the constraints to force that each location will be visited only once, etc. But I have problems to constraint that all locations from selected purchases are visited.
Is it possible to define the problem to be solved using linear programming?. An ideal formulation will group the purchases in groups, not just get a fixed of 4 first, and so on. Is it an instance of the TSP?. Will be possible to find an optimal solution if we have 1,000 purchases and 3,000 locations (assuming that it is possible to group more than 4).

This problem is a variant of the Order (Batch) Picking Problem (see this paper abstract https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2452414X22000814). As you defined it, we can see the routing part as a MTSP, but it has also the batching phase that let things harder.
The problem with your initial formulation is that you do not link the visit variables Ti,j with the orders variable. Actually, you don't really need the X variable, you need just define a new index to the T variable to link it to a route (or a order picking route), so you can create a constraint like  Σr ∈ R Tr,i,j ≤ 4.
Of course that this constraint is based in a very simplified scenario in which you know the maximum amount of products collected in each route and the maximum number of routes. If you want more flexibility more constraints will be needed.
From my experience, this problem, with this size, is not easy solve to optimality in a regular solver as Gurobi/CPLEX, mainly if the max number of products by route is large. Maybe with 3 or 2 products you can solve some instances.
